# Update common increment value to a set of duplicate records

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a scenario like this,

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
--------------------------
1 | null| Axy | Zcd
2 | null| Axy | Zcd
3 | null| Bxy | Yef
4 | null| Bxy | Yef
5 | null| Cvw | Dgh
```

I'm trying to update Col2 to assign a common incremental value to set of duplicates , tried SQL with auto-increment after identifying the duplicates, but the issues is each row is getting increment with different value, 
I'm using this query in DB2 LUW 9.7

```
update tab1 t1
set t1.col2='A'|| seq_tab1.nextval  --sequence
  where exists (
    SELECT col2,trim(upper(col3)) col3,trim(upper(col4)) col4,col1 FROM tab1 t
      where (col2 ='' or col2 is null)
      and trim(upper(t1.col3)) = trim(upper(t.col3)) 
      AND trim(upper(t1.col4)) = trim(upper(t.col4)) 
      and t1.col1=t.col1
      GROUP BY col2,trim(upper(col3)),trim(upper(col4)),col1
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1) 
     and (t1.col2 ='' or t1.col2 is null);
```

result

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
--------------------------
1 | A1| Axy | Zcd
2 | A2| Axy | Zcd
3 | A3| Bxy | Yef
4 | A4| Bxy | Yef
5 | A5| Cvw | Dgh
```

expected output

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
--------------------------
1 | A1| Axy | Zcd
2 | A1| Axy | Zcd
3 | A2| Bxy | Yef
4 | A2| Bxy | Yef
5 | A3| Cvw | Dgh
```

any recommendations ??

Answer (score 0):

Tried this query, which I used in my update

```
select  col1,col2,col3,rn 
from (
select  col1,col2,col3
,dense_rank() over (order by col2 nulls last) as rn
from tab1
where (col1 ='' or col1 is null)
) s1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
update tab1 f1                                            
set f1.new=(
select 'A' || f3.rang from 
            (                                 
            select f2.Col1, 
            dense_rank() over(order by f2.Col3, f2.Col4) rang                                         
            from tab1 f2 order by f2.Col1
            ) f3                                          
where f1.Col1=f3.Col1                        
)                                                              
where exists                                                   
(                                                              
   select * from tab1 f2                                  
   where f1.Col1=f2.Col1                     
)
```